# Unable to install package via npm install

Tags: 16.04, nodejs, npm

Error output

```
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
```

It's stuck for long time and give the above error.

```
system not behind any proxy.
os version ubuntu 16.04.3 lts
node version 8.11.3
npm version 5.6.0
```

when I type `npm -v`, it's showing another error `npm` update check failed.

[image: main error description]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I highly recommend that you update your system to 16.04.5 with the command `sudo apt update&&sudo apt upgrade;`

Answer (score 0):

Update your npm version.

1. `sudo npm cache clean -f`
2. `sudo npm install -g n`
3. `sudo n stable`
4. `npm -v` it should print `6.4.0`.

Alternatively you ca just type `sudo npm install npm@latest -g` in terminal

> (Note: this will update it to the latest stable version)

Visit [this link](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/) for more details.

Comment: already did it..same error rollbackfailedoperational